# Xcode 6 iOS 8 UITableView rowHeight property returns -1

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios8, xcode6, row-height

I have a `UITableView` in Xcode in my project and I set `rowHeight` to be `44` in `StoryBoard`.

In iOS7 everything is fine but in iOS8 rowHeight returns a value of **-1** which cause my table view not being displayed.

Comment: Duplicated indeed. @Js Lim answer in duplicated question solved this.

Answer (score 3):

In iOS 8, Apple introduces a new feature for UITableView known as Self Sizing Cells. 
If you want to display dynamic content in table view with variable height, you would need to calculate the row height manually.

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Here is demo http://www.appcoda.com/self-sizing-cells/

Comment: Thanks but content is not dynamic and cell height is the same always for all cells.